# cordova.file got undefined

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins

i work arround this issus for many day.

i want to use cordova-plugin-file to read/write file on android but it cause me an issus : cordova.file is undefined.

my project is created with ionic framework here is the list of information about plugin version :

- ionic framework : 1.5.5
- cordova version : 5.1.1
- cordova plugin list:

  cordova-plugin-file 4.1.0 "File" 
  cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.2-dev "Whitelist"

anyone can help me to fix this problem :)

Comment: Check this link: http://ngcordova.com/docs/common-issues/

Comment: Did you refrence cordova.js ? Try to use file plugin codes after the app fully loaded